# How do I provide to my customers the ability to map their custom domains with my SAAS app?

Tags: node.js, nginx, dns, wildcard-subdomain

I am working on a MEAN stack SAAS application where I provide each user with their own unique subdomain. For example, the user John Doe has the following subdomain to his name: johndoe.website.com.

Now, if John, **the user, wants to map his subdomain to his own custom domain or subdomain**, for instance, register.johndoe.com/registraton, he should be able to do that.

How can I accomplish this?

I am looking for steps to **accomplish this using NGINX and Node js** in a manner that will lead to minimal changes to our existing code base.

I have searched the internet, and I was unable to find a resource that can serve as a step-by-step guide to help me solve this problem.

I know that the solution would involve the creation of Server Blocks to handle wildcard subdomains using NGINX, but I am not sure about the exact steps that will have to be implemented to get this done.

Comment: This will be a tad more tricky, you'll need to dedicate the nginx to just this application, either with just single server block or with a server_name set to regex `~.`. Then nginx will process all requests no matter what the domain name is. Then just check the url in your app and check if any user has such a domain name as mapping. Ask users to add a cname mapping with value set to the full subdomain.example.com in their domain dns and everything will work.

Comment: @MatJ: Thanks again. Much appreciated.

Comment: No problem... Glad to help.

Comment: @MatJ: I had a couple of follow up questions: 1. Since we want to generate subdomains on the fly, we have implemented wildcard subdomains to accomplish that. Now, if we want to provide custom domain mapping to a user, can't we ask all users to edit their DNS records by adding value = domain.website.com that would be common across all users. Later on, when a we receive a request from a custom domain, we just check the URL and respond accordingly. I would appreciate it if you can respond, please

Comment: @MatJ: As you suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61226187/how-to-create-handle-subdomains-on-the-fly-using-nginx-and-node-js, in a multi-tenant setup, creation of subfolders isn't necessary. Would this change if I provide the user with custom domain mapping as well as a subdomain on my website?